# Converting str to int in python from string slice

Tags: python

I am busy creating a game and am using a text file to store player information and game states.
I am busy using a string to store the information and then taking slices of it for each data point.
I need to assign an int() to a variable but since I am taking slices from a string the slice containing the information is an str(). I have tried to use the int() function and am not coming right.
Please could somebody help.

#i'm getting this error message

```
Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: That error message means you called `int()` on an empty string.

Comment: check for empty strings '' befoer converting

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should check for an empty string and only convert it to an `int` if it's not empty, for example:

```
text = "2324344562396953"

i = 0
step = 2
while True:
    # get slice of string
    ts = text[i: i + step]
    if len(ts):
        # this will execute if ts is not an empty string
        intvar = int(ts)
        print(intvar)
    else:
        # do something else, e.g., break out the loop
        break
    i += step
```

Or, you could use a `try... except` statement, e.g.,

```
text = "2324344562396953"

i = 0
step = 2
while True:
    # get slice of string
    ts = text[i: i + step]
    try:
        intvar = int(ts)
        print(intvar)
    except ValueError:
        # do something else, e.g., break out the loop
        break
    i += step
```

Comment: Nevermind... I managed to solve the problem I had "000" stored in the string and it did not fit the string format.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...
I managed to solve the problem
I had "000" stored in the string and it did not fit the string format.